# multi-factor time-varying CAPM using kalman filter

Tags: finance, kalman-filter, state-space-models, dlm

I am trying to implement a time-varying [CAPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_asset_pricing_model) model using the kalman filter.
I have already found numerous [examples](http://lalas.github.io/quantitativeThoughts/r/2014/09/01/dlmTutorial.html#topic4.1) in R and python using the DLM and the pykalman packages but the problem is that they include a single independent variable while I am aiming for multiple factors. I gave it a shot modifying these examples so as to include another factor (or independent variable) but the betas of the factors don't necessarily sum up to one (which is a constraint when decomposing returns)

Is there any way to impose this constraint during the kalman filter calculation using DLM or pykalman? Or, in general, is there any way to impose this constraint in the kalman filter algorithm?

**EDIT:** - response to Mr F. Tusell:

Thanks a lot for sharing your paper and the corresponding code, just a couple of questions:

1. As far as I understand from the code, the application of the paper is still univariable, correct?...meaning, the 'market' variable in the code is one-dimensional.
2. If I would like to analyze one variate (let's say 'Telecom' industry) and use all the three factors from the Fama French would a similar approach work?
3. In case I am OK with negative betas, should I just set the 'lower' in the optimization process to '-100'?
4. Could you please give more regarding the use of the control variable during the optimization? Could you also share the reasoning behind initializing the 'ini' vector with the values '0.05' and '8'?

**EDIT2:** - response to Mr F. Tusell No2:

Thanks again for the help.

1. Regarding the rationale of having the betas of a univariate analysis with multiple factors:

   Imagine a mutual fund for which we have the returns and we are trying to drill into these so as to get a better understanding. So let's say we know that they are investing in three indices and we want to decompose the return in these... in this case, the 'betas' (which are not really betas anymore) will tell us that they are +50% in index1, +80% in index2 and -30% in index3.
2. I tried to incorporate in your code the multifactor approach, but I am getting the following issues:

i. The 'betas' don't sum up to 1. I tried multiple approaches with upper/lower limits, initial values etc and in all of them the average of the sum is close to zero with a volatility of around 5-10.

ii. The betas have unrealistic values... around 1k - pending on the volatility I enter on the 'C0' array.

I am copying the code below (skipped the data reading part which is exactly the same as in your code) - any comment welcome

```
RWs <- function(par,x) {
  mod <- dlm(FF = matrix(1, nrow = 2, ncol=3), V  = diag(nc+1), W  = diag(3), GG = diag(3), m0 = rep(0,ncol(x)), C0 = 10^7*diag(3),
             JFF= rbind(matrix(1:ncol(market),nrow=1),matrix(1:ncol(market),nrow=1)), X = x)
  diag(mod$W) = par[1:3]
  diag(mod$V) = c(par[4],0)
  return(mod)
}

nc <- 1
N         <- nrow(series)
market    <- matrix(FFfact[,c(1,2,3)],N,3)
y         <- cbind(coredata(series)[,1:nc],1)
np <- 2*nc
ini <- c(rep(0.005,nc),rep(8,nc))

ObsMatrix <- rbind(diag(nc),1)
TrnMatrix <- diag(nc)
LocMatrix <- rbind(diag(nc),rep(0,nc))

par = c(0.01,0.01,0.01,1)

RWs.fit  <- dlmMLE(y, x=market, parm=par, build=RWs)

mod <- RWs(RWs.fit$par,x=market)
betas <- zoo(dlmFilter(y,mod)$a,order.by=index(series))
```

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I wrote [this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/no0kztfdxwg7bix/betas2.pdf?dl=0) with a co-worker (which was summarily rejected when we submitted for publication...). It answers precisely the question you ask.

Are you sure betas add up to one? I am no expert in Finance, but I had the impression that perhaps a weighted average of betas (using relative market capitalizacion as weights) might add up to 1, rather than the betas themselves. Even of that I am not sure.

**Answer to EDIT: of the original question:**

- 1 & 2: Yes, the approach carries forward to any number of factors. However, while I am able to rationalize a restriction such as the average (or weighted average)  of the betas being 1 when the single factor is excess market return over the non-risk asset, I think in the three factor model there is no obvious restriction to enforce.

  No, the "response" is multivariate. In order to impose a (soft) restriction on the betas, you have to estimate all of them at once. The dimension of the
  state vector (=number of sectors dealt with at once) in chunck 2, for instance, is nc=10.
- 3: In general, you can set 'lower' and 'upper' in the maximization routines to whatever values you think are reasonable bounds for the parameters. You must be aware, though, that the parameters in this model are the **variances** of the state and observation noises and cannot therefore be negative. The (time-varying) betas are computed in the state.
- 4: Rational for 0.05 and 8: simply we found (by trial and error) that these are reasonable initial values to achieve convergence of the MLE. In practice youj would try different sets of starting values

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick response and sharing your paper.

Comment: ...I think that 
 RBSA expects the betas to sum up to 1, but, obviously, taking into account the market capitalization adds value. Would it be possible to share some technical (code) details regarding your implementation?

Comment: No sure I understand your comment regarding market capitalization adds value. Yes, I can send you my code (in R) or try to help you otherwise.

Comment: yes, sorry, I pressed the 'Enter' and posted a comment by mistake - I mean that I agree that it makes sense to add the market capitalization as a weighting in the betas - one possible issue though would arise in case there are 'technical' factors included for which there is no market value. Sure if you can send me your R code it would be really helpful.

Comment: ￼There you find it. It will last only a few days.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzgrbqi9dkuxvcm/betas2.R?dl=0

Comment: thanks a lot for that - I will go through it and come back to you.

Comment: thanks again for the help, I have edited my question with some feedback

Comment: thanks, I have edited my question with some modifications in the code you sent me trying to run the multifactor approach and added some more points

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and in the part that shows does not make much sense to me. You seem to have tweaked the code provided without really understanding what it does. I do not understand JFF having all ones,nor what is intended.

Comment: 1. My code is complete - As mentioned in my comment it doesn't contain the data reading part which is exactly the same as your code - I guess it wouldn't be of any use to send you back the piece of code that you sent me 2. I have already explained quite clearly what I am trying to achieve and, trust me, it makes sense  3. I do understand what the dlm package does and what your code was trying to do. 4. Thanks for the help so far, but if you are unable to further support, it's better to just not reply instead of writing down a few random accusations

Comment: As I mentioned, I fail to see what is the purpose of JFF being all  ones. A  $h$ entry in JFF means that the corresponding element in FF is taken from the $h$-th column of $X$. If all elements in JFF are one, all elements in FF are equal  and only one column of $X$ is used. One wonders then what a three column 'market' is doing and what is the purpose of  'LocMatrix' and other objects, defined but never used. I am not in the bussiness of accusing anyone of anything, I have only tried to help. To no avail, it seems.

Comment: I quickly went through the code of the dlm package this morning and copying the logic of the dlmModReg function I modified the JFF (your latest hint confirms this finding) and while the numbers are more sensible still they don't sum up to 1 - I guess I will need to go through and the R and C code of the package to find out how/if it's possible to get this or check for another software solution.